# Google Sheets: Resize columns to all match based on date data

Tags: google-sheets

Not sure if this is possible but I have 4 sets of data that span across the same date range but there is a different amount of data total for each set.

Is there a way to resize the smaller data sets to match the size of the largest, while preserving what date that data is for?

[image: Multiple Columns that need to Match]

Answer (score 1):

select columns and double-click the column border:

[image]